# "I am having..."

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, descriptive-grammar

People say "I'm having a baby." "I'm having a good time," or "I'm having friends over for dinner." but normally don't say "I'm having a car," "I'm having a cold." or "I'm having a solution."

The typical "reasons" found in grammar books for this is that simple present is used for facts, and present progressive is used for temporary situations or when we don't know the exact start time of an activity.  Or, the speaker will make a "choice" about what they want to say, so that the reason they said "The bus is leaving at 08:00" and not "The bus leaves at 08:00." is because they want to stress the temporary nature of the bus' departure time.  This kind of duality often happens in ESL textbooks, for example in the travel chapters where the focus is not on simple present / present progressive usage but on vocabulary or collocations, so the authors are not as vigilant about being "consistent" with their usage.

So, the reasons I have heard for why we don't say "I'm owning a car." is because owning a car is a fact.  I can see that "logic" but what about "I have a headache."?  I have never heard a native speaker say "I am having a headache," or "I was having a headache when you asked me about the files."  Do you own a headache?  Surely, it is temporary and merits the progressive tense.  What about "I have brown eyes."?  Colored contact lenses aside, I think everyone, native and non-native speakers would agree that "I am having brown eyes." is not something English speakers would say.

Is the choice between using present progressive and simple present idiomatic?  For the case of "I have a headache / cold / toothache, etc." I have never heard my dad use the present progressive.  I grew up hearing "Mommy has a headache so leave her alone." or "I have a cold, so I'm not going to the office today."  So, I just learned those expressions and after 46 years it is set in stone as the "right" way to speak.

Are there deeper reasons for these differences in usage or is it just a matter of "that's the way it's expressed and it's stupid to question it."?  Is there a difference because English has a progressive tense, thereby making these kinds of problems more apparent?  Was there a time in the history of English when speakers said "I am having a headache / cold / toothache."?

Comment: Who told you "we can" and "we can't"? Please include your reference/research in the question. Otherwise, it would be "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: You edited your question. What people? American? British? Canadian? Irish? Or Californian?

Comment: @Mari-LouA You don't own "cold". It is closer to "experiencing/suffering".

Comment: You don't know? The second series of examples is using "have" as in owning something: I possess a car/cold/solution = "I have got a car/cold/solution." E.g I have measles/chickenpox/back pain etc. Whereas the previous line,   *have* means *experience* (I will be a mother; I am enjoying myself), or *invite* (I have invited friends for dinner)

Comment: Why are you asking? Was this a student's question? Look it up in a dictionary http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have and here: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/have lots of different uses for *have*

Comment: @Mari-LouA well I understand have indicates ownership but if I had to explain why the other options don't work to a student I'm not sure I would have a satisfying answer. We can say I'm having an experience but not I'm having a cold.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Your explanation doesn't work. Do you mean you can't say, "I am having a toothache/back pain/cold"? I am sure I can say that.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm asking because students have asked and I can't find satisfying answers in any of my books.

Comment: @Rathony no, "I'm having a cold" is not standard English.  You say what you want but I choose not to speak that kind of English.  And Californian is not a kind of English.

Comment: Your question should be approached with "concept of time". If you have a back pain that has lasted for a long time, you should not use "I am having a back pain." If you feel your back pain right after you lift something very heavy or you get kicked in the back, you can say "I am having a back pain." as it is temporary and may not be long-lasting.

Comment: Why do you think Californian is not a kind of English? They are larger than Great Britain in terms of GDP, population, etc.

Comment: @Rathony I wouldn't say "I'm having a toothache", although the discomfort is temporary, the pain I'm enduring is something that is beyond my will, I am in pain states a fact, and *have* is being used as a stative verb. I was previously  referring to being rash in saying that someone owns or possess a cold, that was inaccurate. In illnesses, *have* means to suffer.

Comment: I shouldn't have posted any comments, I had an urgent matter to attend to and so left a half-baked comment, and read the following comments even more hurriedly. Sorry!

Comment: Perhaps one should stop trying to look for perfect logic in the language and realize that it evolved naturally and need not have completely logical rules. We simply don't say "I'm having a cold" because it's just not what you say.

Comment: @MattSamuel I'm not looking for perfect logic, I'm looking for a way to explain this to myself but also to my students.  I'm tired of giving answers such as "That's the way we say it."  This kind of question is completely OK for someone whose L1 doesn't have the progressive tense.  In Chinese, they say "I head hurt." so when they learn English they have to make a decision about how to express "headache" in a way English speakers can understand.  They learned the phrase in school but when it comes time to make a sentence not taught in school, there is trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two facts interacting here

> 1. The Progressive construction is not used with [stative predicates](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/predtypes.pdf). 
>      Another way to put this is that if a predicate is used in the Progressive, it will be interpreted as an Active predicate, if possible. 
>      If this is not possible, you get an ungrammatical sentence.
> 2. The verb *have* is a widely-used auxiliary verb, and participates in many idioms and constructions; some of these are active and some are stative. There is also the 'Possess' sense of *have*, which is normally stative.

Basically, you can't say *I'm having a car* or *I'm having the answer* because those predicates are stative. *I'm having a headache*, on the other hand, like *She's having a baby*, can be considered active; it is interpretable as an event with a beginning, middle, and end.

Some examples of active idioms with *have* (that are therefore OK in the Progressive)

- *She's having a baby in November.*
- *He's having lunch right now.*
- *She was having a cigar when he came in.*
- *He's having to do it all over again.*
- *She's having her ring resized.*

.. as well as the ones mentioned in the question.
If they're active predicates, Progressive is allowed. But not statives.

Comment: So, if I understand this issue and your answer, there is an internal logic to English which doesn't support certain uses of verbs.  If we did accept these uses then the other uses would have to change.  So grammatically it is possible to say certain things but semantically it would be inconsistent with the other uses in the system.

Comment: Yes. The internal logic is English syntax; it's what we have for grammar instead of lots of endings and paradigms, the way Russian or German have. There are hundreds (probably thousands) of [syntactic rules in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf), and they interact, like this. I'm not sure what you mean by your last two sentences, however.

Comment: Well, what I mean is that is possible to say the sentence "I am having a car." but the use of "having" doesn't match other uses in the system so it is inconsistent and causes native speakers to say "That doesn't sound right."  I'm trying to find a way to explain why what students think is right doesn't work in English without using words like "inchoative" "stative" or "atelic."  My students are intelligent people but their listening skills are often weak so explanations need to be clear and not use grammar-speak.

Comment: A good learner's Dictionary should distinguish active from stative verbs, just like mass from count nouns; you have to deal with both eventually. It's mostly semantic, but there are plenty of odd cases; for instance, _rent_ (in both senses) is active, but _own_ is stative. Hence, _I am renting a house to/from him_, but not **I am owning a house on this street.*

Comment: I think your "I'm having a headache" is wrong. Read this (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/have-got-and-have) article which mentions same sentence as wrong.

Comment: First, I was speaking of American English. Second, there is nothing grammatically wrong with _I'm having a headache_; it's an ordinary English sentence describing the speaker's current status. _I have a headache_ could also describe the same status, but it wouldn't have any connotations of temporariness like the progressive form does. As for the reference, English dictionaries are not the place to go for grammar assistance. Try an English grammar instead.

Comment: @JohnLawler Ok, thank you for your inputs. Could you recommend me some online reference where I can learn English Grammar. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar was the best I could find and since it was from Cambridge so I trusted it.