# Does "is" always distinguish a subject and predicate ?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subjects, predicate

"Martin thinks he is a cat"

Martin is the subject and thinking he is the cat is the predicate, right ?

Is there ever such a thing as a sentence with "is" more than once, but only one subject and predicate ?

Comment: A sentence can have multiple clauses, with each clause (by definition) having its own subject and predicate. Thus you could theoretically string together an infinite number of clauses, with each optionally using "is" as its verb in its predicate. For example: "Martin IS a person who thinks he IS a cat that the dog IS happy to see."

Answer (score 1):

> "Martin thinks he is a cat."

This exactly equivalent to "Martin thinks *that* he is a cat"

'that' is a relative pronoun.

'[that] he is a cat' is a subordinate clause.

Comment: "That" is not a relative pronoun but a conjunction.

Comment: Not according to this and many other websites -> http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subordinateclause.htm

Comment: Sorry I can't open the link. When you use "relative" before pronoun or adverb, it indicates there is an "antecedent" bofore it. It is its primary function to "relate" the clause to the "antecedent". There is no antecedent in the sentence. Therefore, it is not a relative pronoun. And "pronoun" itself has a specific meaning and function, too.

Comment: Try this link. http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subordinate_clause.htm -   Failing that you can search online for   ***"subordinate clause"  "relative pronoun"***

Comment: I could open the link which explains exactly what a "relative pronoun" and "subordinate clause" are. There is not a single exmaple that shows the OP's "that" is a relative pronoun.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I dunno, bro...I've been watching you two go at it...I think Rathony might be right...I think you got truncheoned by the conjunction cop.

Comment: @michael_timofeev What happened to your "I am having a cold" question? Did you delete it? Why?

Comment: @Rathony no, professor Lawler answered it.

Comment: @michael_timofeev I couldn't find it today. Can you show me the link?

Comment: @Rathony http://english.stackexchange.com/q/284151/129806

Comment: @michael_timofeev Thanks. Good to know his answer is in line with my comments.